# How to import an interface in external ngModule library

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new on angular 4
I created a ngModule package named `mds.angular.bootstrap.datetimepicker` with the following `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "mds.angular.bootstrap.datetimepicker",
  "version": "0.9.8",
  "description": "Persian and gregorian DateTimePicker with angular 4",
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "./mds-datetimePicker.module.js",
  "types": [
    "./mds-datetimePicker.module.d.ts",
    "./assests/date.interface.d.ts",
    "./assests/day.interface.d.ts",
    "./assests/rangeDate.interface.d.ts"
  ],
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "author": {
    "email": "mds_soft@yahoo.com",
    "name": "Mohammad Dayyan",
    "url": "https://github.com/Mds92/mds-angular-bootstrap-datetime-picker"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "public",
    "url": "https://github.com/Mds92/mds-angular-bootstrap-datetime-picker"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/Mds92/mds-angular-bootstrap-datetime-picker",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "mds.persian.calendar": "^0.9.69",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  }
}
```

I publish it on `npm` and it's OK
Now I want to consume the package in another angular 4 project.
So I install the package `npm install mds.angular.bootstrap.datetimepicker --save`
I use it as the following

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { MdsDatetimePickerModule } from 'mds.angular.bootstrap.datetimepicker';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    MdsDatetimePickerModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

It's OK until here, But I have to import `IDate` from `mds.angular.bootstrap.datetimepicker` package to use it in my component
But it throws exception:

```
ERROR in D:/Sources/sample/src/app/app.component.ts (2,23): Cannot find module 'date.interface'.


import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IDate } from 'date.interface'; //ERROR

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Mds Angular Bootstrap DateTimePicker';
  viewInit = false;

  inLinePersianDateTimePicker = '';
  inlinePersianDatePickerChanged(selectedDate: IDate) {
    if (!this.viewInit) return;
    this.inLinePersianDateTimePicker = selectedDate.formatString;
  }

  inLineGregorianDateTimePicker = '';
  inlineGregorianDatePickerChanged(selectedDate: IDate) {
    if (!this.viewInit) return;
    this.inLineGregorianDateTimePicker = selectedDate.formatString;
  }

  popoverPersianDateTimePicker = '';
  popoverPersianDateTimePickerChanged(selectedDate: IDate) {
    if (!this.viewInit) return;
    this.popoverPersianDateTimePicker = selectedDate.formatString;
  }

  popoverGregorianDateTimePicker = '';
  popoverGregorianDateTimePickerChanged(selectedDate: IDate) {
    if (!this.viewInit) return;
    this.popoverGregorianDateTimePicker = selectedDate.formatString;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.viewInit = true;
  }
}
```

The following is `IDate` in `mds.angular.bootstrap.datetimepicker` package

```
export interface IDate {
  year: number;
  month: number;
  day: number;
  hour: number;
  minute: number;
  second: number;
  millisecond: number;
  formatString: string;
}
```

How should I use `IDate` in external applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution:

**First:** Creating `index.ts` (I named it index, you can change the name) and write `export` for each type we want to use in external libraries.

```
export * from "./mds-datetimePicker.module";
export * from "./services/mds-datetime-picker-resources.service";
export * from "./components/mds-datetime-picker.component";
export * from "./components/core/mds-datetime-picker-core.component";
export * from "./assests/date.interface";
export * from "./assests/day.interface";
export * from "./assests/mds-datetime-picker.utility";
export * from "./assests/rangeDate.interface";
```

**Second:** open command prompt and choose `package.json` path, then write the following command:

```
tsc --declaration
```

you can write `tsc -d` instead.
This command compiles typescript files and creates `*.d.ts` files

**Finally:** In `package.json` add the following lines:

```
"main": "./index.js",
"types": "./index.d.ts"
```

Now, we can import all of types in `index.ts` as the following:

```
import { MdsDatetimePickerModule, IDate } from 'mds.angular.bootstrap.datetimepicker';
```

Comment: is the tsc important? why cant angular do it right away?